# Why sound play doesn't use festival's default voice?

Tags: ros, sound-play

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to make our pr2 speak. However the (sound_play node + say.py script) gives a deep and slow voice hardly understandable. I changed voices in festival, but sound_play doesn't take it into account.
How to make sound_play use the voice set as default in festival ?

Guido

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10221/why-sound-play-doesn%27t-use-festival%27s-default-voice-?/) by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) on ROS Answers with karma: 514 on 2011-06-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Guido,

I submitted a [ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4940) for the "deep slow voice" issue about 6 weeks ago.  In the meantime, the only way I figured out how to change the voice is as follows.  (This applies to Ubuntu 10.04 with Diamondback debian packages and Festival debian packages.)

$ cd /usr/share/festival
<br>
$ sudo pico voices.scm

(Or use whatever editor you like instead of pico.)

Once in the editor, search for "kal_diphone" (without the quotes).  Change this to "don_diphone" (again without the quotes).

Save changes and exit the editor.

You should now hear a better voice when using sound_play node + say.py.

--patrick

---

Originally posted by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) with karma: 4046 on 2011-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dimitar Simeonov](https://answers.ros.org/users/256/dimitar-simeonov/) on 2011-07-22**:
Hi Guido, when you solve this can you please post the solution? Thanks

**Comment by [Guido](https://answers.ros.org/users/279/guido/) on 2011-06-21**:
Thanks for the answer. Sadly, it doesn't changed the voice. I changed "kal_diphone" to "voice_cmu_us_bdl_arctic_clunits" but it didn't worked. I tryed with don_diphone without success. I still get a ugly voice.

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-06-14**:
i'll fix that soon!